# is there a way to set start delay for Dynamic Animation(Spring Animation) in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android-animation

is there a way to set start delay for Dynamic Animation(Spring Animation) in Android like the native animations..

Comment: you should add tags to your post like spring android so your question is find easily by other users. you should also take more time to describe what you want to to obtain and what you already tried. add code snippets of code working with native animation too

Answer (score -1):

According to this react-native issue [Spring animation with delay](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12474) from 2017 it seems that it is not possible to do.

Animated.delay supports it.